# Android-How to show image round edge in Listview

Tags: android

I want to use SimpleAdapter, and do not want to overwrite Adapter. Is it realized by writing the ListView Layout file and let the image show round edge after uploading. I find some reference, and write the code like this.I do not understand how to pass the parameter. Anyone’s right direction is thankful.

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
            String textRepresentation) {

        if(view instanceof ImageView  && data instanceof Bitmap){
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;

            iv.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) data);
            return true;
        }else
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the  tag to create a drawable in XML with rounded corners. (You can do other stuff with the shape tag like define a color gradient as well).

Here's a copy of a XML file I'm using in one of my apps to create a drawable with a white background, black border and rounded corners:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>    

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            />

    <padding android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"
             /> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Comment: thanks very much，but how to use the XML file to upload image?

Comment: save this as a xml inside drawable folder. And set the background of your imageview as R.drawable.your_xml_file